# WSO2 - Features currently supported by enterprises mobility manager?

Tags: wso2, mdm

I would like to know whether current version of enterprise mobility manager support Email containerization via Nitrodesk Touchdown & app containerization? If yes, Please provide me the steps..

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 EMM does not support Email containerization & app containerization at the moment. But you could use WSO2 EMM to configure Email settings & control the apps that can be installed on a device.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 EMM supports email containerization via Nitrodesk touchdown. Anyway this goes with the support customers. But app containerization is not supported at the moment. For app containerization strategies you may look at Knox or iOS provided containerization strategies to be integrated into this.